# Creating a vertex weighted graph based on edge weights

Tags: graph-theory

I'm developing an algorithm that would allow me to create a vertex weighted graph based on the conditions of the edge weights. The problem I'm coming across is keeping the consistency of the shortest path. For instance, this is the current graph I'm trying to convert. Assume that all the edge weights will be positive.

[image: Graph Image]

I've tried multiple combinations to come up with an algorithm that could work, but so far nothing has come up to what I want it to be. I've tried summing, multiplying, subtraction, priority based numbering, but to no avail. Is it even possible to come up with a way to convert edge weights to vertex weights?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what is the sense of the vertex weights you are looking for, since distances to the same vertex from a couple different vertices may be different.

This, however, would not be a problem if the graph had a uniquely designated source vertex $s$. In this case, the weight of $s$ would be $0$ and you can set the weight of other vertices as the cheapest last step of an $s \to v$ path, effectively computing it from a single source shortest path computation, provided e.g. by Dijkstra's Algorithm (if all weights are assumed non-negative) or by the Bellman Ford Algorithm (if edge weights can be negative).

In your specific graph, here would be the implied weights $w$:
$w(s) = 0, w(a) = 6, w(b) = 3, w(c) = 1, w(e) = 3, w(f) = 1, w(z) = 3$.

The alternative is to pull the weights directly from the shortest path:
$w(s) = 0, w(a) = 6, w(b) = 3, w(c) = 4, w(e) = 7, w(f) = 8, w(z) = 11$.